# new to scrapy and table data extraction

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

First day on scrappy and I want to get the table data in this

```
http://www.cottagehealthsystem.org/tabid/149/Default.aspx
```

so I want

Administration  569-7290
Anesthesia  569-7206
Birth Center    569-7232
Cancer Data Center  569-8280
Cardiac Care Unit   569-7222
Cardiac Electrophysiology   569-8234
Cardiac Rehabilitation  569-7201
Cardiology  569-8284
 etc etc

I did this

```
scrapy shell "http://www.cottagehealthsystem.org/tabid/149/Default.aspx"
response.selector.xpath('//table//td//text()').extract()
```

and it gives me a lot of unuseful data like this

```
[u'\n\t\t\t',
 u'\n                    Home\n                    ',
 u'\n                    \xa0|\xa0\n                    ',
 u'\n                    Patient & Visitor Info\n                    ',
 u'\n                    \xa0|\xa0\n                    ',
 u'\n                        Maps & Directions\n                    ',
 u'\n                    \xa0|\xa0\n                    ',
 u'\n                    Careers\n                    ',
 u'\n                    \xa0|\xa0\n                 ',
 u'\n                        Contact Us\n                    ',
 u'\n                    \xa0|\xa0\n                    ',
 u'                         Find a Physician  ',
 u'\n                ',
 u'\n                    \n                    ',
 u'\n                    ',
 u'\n                    ',
 u'Search',
 u'\n                    ',
 u'\r\n',
 u'\r\n.xsImgSearch { MARGIN-RIGHT: 2px }\r\n.xsCmdSearch { text-transform: uppercase; COLOR: #ffffff; BORDER: 0px; PADDING-RIGHT: 3px; PADDING-LEFT: 3px; FONT-SIZE: 8pt; MARGIN-RIGHT: 2px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #006b6e }\r\n.xsTxtSearch { BORDER: #7f9db9 1px solid; FONT-SIZE: 9pt; WIDTH: 90px; MARGIN-RIGHT: 2px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #ffffff }\r\n',
 u'\r\n',
 u'\r\n\t',
 u'\r\n\t\t',
 u'\r\n\t\t\t',
 u'\r\n\t\t\t',
 u'\r\n\t\t',
 u'\r\n\t',
 u'\r\n',
 u'\r\n',
 u'\n                    ',
 u'\n                    ',
 u'\n                ',
 u'\n                ',
 u'\n            ',
 u'\r\n\r\n',
 u'\r\n.isReferencedModuleBorder\r\n{\r\n    border: solid orange 1px;\r\n    border-bottom: solid #ff0000 0px;\r\n}\r\n.isReferencedModuleText\r\n{\r\n    color:orange;\r\n    border: solid orange 1px;\r\n    border-top: solid orange 0px;\r\n    text-align:center;\r\n}\r\n\r\n\r\n',
 u'\r\n\r\n',
 u'\r\n    \r\n    \r\n    ',
 u'\r\n\t',
 u'\r\n\t',
 u'\r\n',
 u'\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n',
 u'\r\n',
 u'\r\n    \r\n    \r\n',
 u'\n                ',
 u'\n            ',
 u'\r\n\r\n',
 u'\r\n.isReferencedModuleBorder\r\n{\r\n    border: solid orange 1px;\r\n    border-bottom: solid #ff0000 0px;\r\n}\r\n.isReferencedModuleText\r\n{\r\n    color:orange;\r\n    border: solid orange 1px;\r\n    border-top: solid orange 0px;\r\n    text-align:center;\r\n}\r\n\r\n\r\n',
 u'\r\n\r\n',
 u'\r\n    \r\n    \r\n    ',
 u'\r\n\t',
 u'\r\n\t',
 u'\r\n',
 u'\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n',
 u'\r\n',
 u'\r\n    \r\n    \r\n',
 u'\n                ',
 u'\n                    ',
 u'\n                    ',
 u'\n                        ',
 u'\n                            ',
 u'SBCH HEALTH SERVICES',
 u'\xa0',
 u'PATIENT & VISITOR INFO',
 u'\xa0',
 u'EVENTS & CLASSES',
 u'\xa0',
 u'DIRECTIONS & PARKING',
 u'\xa0',
 u'SBCH MAPS',
 u'\xa0',
 u'GIFT SHOP',
 u'\xa0',
 u'VISITOR DINING',
 u'\xa0',
 u'SANTA BARBARA COTTAGE HOSPITAL FOUNDATION',
 u'\xa0',
 u'CONTACT INFORMATION',
 u' \xa0\n                        ',
 u'\n                    ',
 u'\n                    ',
 u'\n                    ',
 u'\n                    ',
 u'\n                        ',
 u'\n                            ',
 u'\n                                ',
 u'\n                                    ',
 u'\n                                        ',
 u'\n                                            ',
 u'\n                                                Santa Barbara\n                                                ',
 u'\n                                                ',
 u'Cottage Hospital',
 u'\n                                            ',
 u'\n                                            ',
 u'\n                                            400 West Pueblo Street',
 u'\n                                            Santa Barbara, CA 93105',
 u'\n                                            805.682.7111\n                                        ',
 u'\n                                    ',
 u'\n                                ',
 u'\n                            ',
 u'\n                        ',
 u'\n                    ',
 u'\n                    ',
 u'\n                ',
 u'                \n            ',
 u'\n                ',
 u'\n                    ',
 u'\n                        ',
 u'\r\n\n                        ',
 u'\r\n\n                    ',
 u'\n\t\t    ',
 u'\n                        \tif(document.getElementById(\'dnn_topLeftContentPane\').innerHTML==""&&document.getElementById(\'dnn_topRightContentPane\').innerHTML=="")\n                        \t{\n                         \t   document.getElementById(\'tr_topLeftRight\').style.display="none";\n                       \t\t}\n                    ',
 u'\n                    ',
 u'\n                        ',
 u'\n                        ',
 u'\n                        ',
 u'\r\n\r\n',
 u'\r\n.isReferencedModuleBorder\r\n{\r\n    border: solid orange 1px;\r\n    border-bottom: solid #ff0000 0px;\r\n}\r\n.isReferencedModuleText\r\n{\r\n    color:orange;\r\n    border: solid orange 1px;\r\n    border-top: solid orange 0px;\r\n    text-align:center;\r\n}\r\n\r\n\r\n',
 u'\r\n\r\n',
 u'\r\n    \r\n    \r\n    ',
 u'\r\n\t',
 u'\r\n\t',
 u'\xa0',
 u'\r\n',
 u'\r\n',
 u'\r\n    ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Postal Address ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Cottage Health System',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Santa Barbara Cottage Hospital',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'PO Box 689',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'400 W. Pueblo Street',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Santa Barbara, CA 93102-0689',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'\xa0',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'\r\n                ',
 u'\r\n                    ',
 u'\r\n                        ',
 u'\u2022',
 u'\r\n                        ',
 u'Main Number',
 u':\xa0 (805) 682-7111',
 u'\r\n                    ',
 u'\r\n                    ',
 u'\r\n                        ',
 u'\u2022',
 u'\r\n                        ',
 u'General Information / Media Inquiries',
 u':\xa0 (805) 879-8980',
 u'\r\n                    ',
 u'\r\n                    ',
 u'\r\n                        ',
 u'\u2022',
 u'\r\n                        ',
 u'Community Concerns Line',
 u':\xa0 (805) 569-8917',
 u'\r\n                    ',
 u'\r\n                    ',
 u'\r\n                        ',
 u'\u2022',
 u'\r\n                        ',
 u'Public Affairs',
 u'\r\n                    ',
 u'\r\n                    ',
 u'\r\n                        ',
 u'\u2022',
 u'\r\n                        ',
 u'Patient Grievances, Complaints, Compliments: chsquality@sbch.org',
 u'\r\n                    ',
 u'\r\n                ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n    ',
 u'\r\n',
 u'\r\n\r\n',
 u'\xa0',
 u'\r\n',
 u'\r\n',
 u'\xa0',
 u'\r\n',
 u'Key Phone Numbers',
 u' (all 805 area code)',
 u'\r\n',
 u'\r\n',
 u'\r\n    ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Administration',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'569-7290',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Anesthesia',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'569-7206',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Birth Center',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'569-7232',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Cancer Data Center',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'569-8280',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Cardiac Care Unit',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'569-7222',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Cardiac Electrophysiology',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'569-8234',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Cardiac Rehabilitation',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'569-7201',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Cardiology',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'569-8284',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Careers / Recruitment',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'879-8799',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Chemical Dependency',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'569-7253',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u"Children's Hospital",
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'569-7273',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Community Concerns Line',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'569-8917',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Community Wellness',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'569-8240',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Construction Project Management Hotline',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'569-8915',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Diabetes Services',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'569-8240',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Development',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'879-8980',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Education',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'569-7325',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Emergency Department',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'569-7210',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Emergency Psychiatric Services',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'569-8339',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Endoscopy Services',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'569-7285',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Enterostomal Therapy',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'569-7385',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Environmental Services',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'569-7205',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Eye & Laser Center',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'569-8260',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Facilities Management',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'569-7318',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Finance',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'879-8935',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Foundation',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'879-8980',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Gift Shop',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'682-7454',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Infection Control',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'569-7204',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Information Systems',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'569-7270',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Interpreter (Translation) Services',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'569-8200',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Laboratory',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'569-7360',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Lifeline',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'569-7572',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Library (Reeves Medical Library)',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'569-7240',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Materials Management',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'569-7209',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Medical Education',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'569-7315',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Medical Records',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'569-7306',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Medical Social Services',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'569-8273',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Neonatology',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'569-7522',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Nutrition',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'569-7216',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Occupational Therapy',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'569-7201',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Outpatient Surgery',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'569-7287',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Pathology',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'569-7367',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Patient Business Services',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'879-8900',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Patient Grievances',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'879-8769',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Pediatric Hematology/Oncology',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'569-8394',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Pediatric Intensive Care Unit',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'569-8297',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Pediatric Services',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'569-7273',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Perinatal Center',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'569-8209',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Pharmacy',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'569-8381',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Psychiatric Services',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'569-7253',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Public Affairs',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'879-8980',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Quality Improvement',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'569-7244',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Radiology',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'569-7279',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Research',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'569-8976',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Respiratory Care',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'569-7207',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Reeves Medical Library',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'569-7240',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Speech Therapy',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'569-7201',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Spiritual Care',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'569-8386',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Surgical Education',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'569-7316',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Surgical Services',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'569-7255',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Therapy Services',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'569-7201',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Utilization Management',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'569-7292',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'Volunteer Services',
 u'\r\n            ',
 u'569-7357',
 u'\r\n        ',
 u'\r\n    ',
 u'\r\n',
 u'\r\n\r\n',
 u'\xa0110413',
 u'\r\n',
 u'\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n',
 u'\r\n',
 u'\r\n    \r\n    \r\n',
 u'\r\n\n                        ',
 u'\n                        ',
 u'\n                    ',
 u'\n\t\t\t',
 u'\n\t\t\t\tif(document.getElementById(\'dnn_ContentPane\').innerHTML=="")\n\t\t\t\t{\n\t\t\t\t\tdocument.getElementById(\'tr_contentPane\').style.display="none";\n\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t',
 u'\n                    ',
 u'\n                        ',
 u'\n                        ',
 u'\n                        ',
 u'\r\n\n                        ',
 u'\n                        ',
 u'\n                    ',
 u'\n\t\t\t',
 u'\n\t\t\t\tif(document.getElementById(\'dnn_bottomLineContentPane\').innerHTML=="")\n\t\t\t\t{\n\t\t\t\t\tdocument.getElementById(\'tr_bottomLine\').style.display="none";\n\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t',
 u'\n                    ',
 u'\n                        ',
 u'\n                        ',
 u'\n                        ',
 u'\r\n\n                        ',
 u'\n                        ',
 u'\n                    ',
 u'\n\t\t\t',
 u'\n\t\t\t\tif(document.getElementById(\'dnn_bottomOneColumnContentPane\').innerHTML=="")\n\t\t\t\t{\n\t\t\t\t\tdocument.getElementById(\'tr_bottomOneCol\').style.display="none";\n\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t',
 u'\n                    ',
 u'\n                        ',
 u'\n                        ',
 u'\n                        ',
 u'\r\n\n                        ',
 u'\r\n\n                        ',
 u'\n                        ',
 u'\n                    ',
 u'\n\t\t\t',
 u'\n                        \tif(document.getElementById(\'dnn_bottomRightNarrowContentPane\').innerHTML==""&&document.getElementById(\'dnn_bottomLeftWideContentPane\').innerHTML=="")\n                        \t{\n                         \t   document.getElementById(\'topBottomThing\').style.display="none";\n                       \t\t}\n                    \t',
 u'\n                    ',
 u'\n                        ',
 u'\n                            ',
 u'\n                                ',
 u'\n                                    ',
 u'\n                                    ',
 u'\n                                    ',
 u'\r\n\n                                    ',
 u'\r\n\n                                    ',
 u'\n                                    ',
 u'\n                                ',
 u'\n                            ',
 u'\n                        ',
 u'\n                    ',
 u'\n\t\t\t\t\t',
 u'\n                        \t\t\tif(document.getElementById(\'dnn_bottomRightWideContentPane\').innerHTML==""&&document.getElementById(\'dnn_bottomLeftNarrowContentPane\').innerHTML=="")\n                        \t\t\t{\n                         \t   \t\t\tdocument.getElementById(\'bottomBottomThing\').style.display="none";\n                       \t\t\t\t}\n                    \t\t\t',
 u'\n\t\t\t',
 u'\n\t\t    ',
 u'\n                        \tif(document.getElementById(\'dnn_bottomRightNarrowContentPane\').innerHTML!=""||document.getElementById(\'dnn_bottomLeftNarrowContentPane\').innerHTML!="")\n                        \t{\n\t\t\t\t   document.getElementById(\'tr_pushup\').style.display="none";\n                       \t\t}\n                    ',
 u'\n                ',
 u'\n            ']
```

please help

ok in shell I tried this

response.selector.xpath('//table//td')

this gives better format but still there is lot of noise

```
 <Selector xpath='//table//td//td' data=u'<td>Public Affairs</td>'>,
 <Selector xpath='//table//td//td' data=u'<td>879-8980</td>'>,
 <Selector xpath='//table//td//td' data=u'<td>Quality Improvement</td>'>,
 <Selector xpath='//table//td//td' data=u'<td>569-7244</td>'>,
 <Selector xpath='//table//td//td' data=u'<td>Radiology</td>'>,
 <Selector xpath='//table//td//td' data=u'<td>569-7279</td>'>,
 <Selector xpath='//table//td//td' data=u'<td>Research</td>'>,
 <Selector xpath='//table//td//td' data=u'<td>569-8976</td>'>,
 <Selector xpath='//table//td//td' data=u'<td>Respiratory Care</td>'>,
 <Selector xpath='//table//td//td' data=u'<td>569-7207</td>'>,
 <Selector xpath='//table//td//td' data=u'<td>Reeves Medical Library</td>'>,
 <Selector xpath='//table//td//td' data=u'<td>569-7240</td>'>,
 <Selector xpath='//table//td//td' data=u'<td>Speech Therapy</td>'>,
 <Selector xpath='//table//td//td' data=u'<td>569-7201</td>'>,
 <Selector xpath='//table//td//td' data=u'<td>Spiritual Care</td>'>,
 <Selector xpath='//table//td//td' data=u'<td>569-8386</td>'>,
 <Selector xpath='//table//td//td' data=u'<td>Surgical Education</td>'>,
 <Selector xpath='//table//td//td' data=u'<td>569-7316</td>'>,
 <Selector xpath='//table//td//td' data=u'<td>Surgical Services</td>'>,
 <Selector xpath='//table//td//td' data=u'<td>569-7255</td>'>,
 <Selector xpath='//table//td//td' data=u'<td>Therapy Services</td>'>,
 <Selector xpath='//table//td//td' data=u'<td>569-7201</td>'>,
 <Selector xpath='//table//td//td' data=u'<td>Utilization Management</td>'>,
 <Selector xpath='//table//td//td' data=u'<td>569-7292</td>'>,
 <Selector xpath='//table//td//td' data=u'<td>Volunteer Services</td>'>,
 <Selector xpath='//table//td//td' data=u'<td>569-7357</td>'>,
 <Selector xpath='//table//td//td' data=u'<td style="height:0px;" class="rightColS'>,
 <Selector xpath='//table//td//td' data=u'<td style="height:0px;" class="leftColSp'>,
 <Selector xpath='//table//td//td' data=u'<td id="dnn_bottomLineContentPane" valig'>,
 <Selector xpath='//table//td//td' data=u'<td style="height:0px;" class="rightColS'>,
 <Selector xpath='//table//td//td' data=u'<td style="height:0px;" class="leftColSp'>,
 <Selector xpath='//table//td//td' data=u'<td id="dnn_bottomOneColumnContentPane" '>,
 <Selector xpath='//table//td//td' data=u'<td style="height:0px;" class="rightColS'>,
 <Selector xpath='//table//td//td' data=u'<td class="leftColSpacer">\n             '>,
 <Selector xpath='//table//td//td' data=u'<td id="dnn_bottomLeftWideContentPane" c'>,
 <Selector xpath='//table//td//td' data=u'<td id="dnn_bottomRightNarrowContentPane'>,
 <Selector xpath='//table//td//td' data=u'<td class="rightColSpacer">\n            '>,
 <Selector xpath='//table//td//td' data=u'<td colspan="6">\n                       '>,
 <Selector xpath='//table//td//td' data=u'<td class="leftColSpacer" valign="top">\n'>,
 <Selector xpath='//table//td//td' data=u'<td id="dnn_bottomLeftNarrowContentPane"'>,
 <Selector xpath='//table//td//td' data=u'<td id="dnn_bottomRightWideContentPane" '>,
 <Selector xpath='//table//td//td' data=u'<td class="rightColSpacer" v
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to modify your xpath so that first you make one selector object for all the `tr` in that table, after that loop through the selector object list and relatively access the `td` of each `tr`. The following code will help you to do so.

```
In [1]: trs = response.xpath('//*[@id="dnn_ctr724_HtmlModule_HtmlModule_lblContent"]/table[2]/tbody/tr')

In [2]: for tr in trs:                                                                                  
    name = tr.xpath('./td[1]//text()').extract()
    value = tr.xpath('./td[2]//text()').extract()
        name = name[0].strip() if name else 'n/a'
        value = value[0].strip() if value else 'n/a'
        print '%s  >>  %s ' % (name, value)
```

the output will be ,

```
Administration  >>  569-7290 
Anesthesia  >>  569-7206 
Birth Center  >>  569-7232 
Cancer Data Center  >>  569-8280 
Cardiac Care Unit  >>  569-7222 
Cardiac Electrophysiology  >>  569-8234 
Cardiac Rehabilitation  >>  569-7201 
Cardiology  >>  569-8284 
Careers / Recruitment  >>  879-8799 
Chemical Dependency  >>  569-7253 
Children\'s Hospital  >>  569-7273 
Community Concerns Line  >>  569-8917 
Community Wellness  >>  569-8240 
Construction Project Management Hotline  >>  569-8915 
Diabetes Services  >>  569-8240 
Development  >>  879-8980 
Education  >>  569-7325 
Emergency Department  >>  569-7210 
Emergency Psychiatric Services  >>  569-8339 
Endoscopy Services  >>  569-7285 
Enterostomal Therapy  >>  569-7385 
Environmental Services  >>  569-7205 
Eye & Laser Center  >>  569-8260 
Facilities Management  >>  569-7318 
Finance  >>  879-8935 
Foundation  >>  879-8980 
Gift Shop  >>  682-7454 
Infection Control  >>  569-7204 
Information Systems  >>  569-7270 
Interpreter (Translation) Services  >>  569-8200 
Laboratory  >>  569-7360 
Lifeline  >>  569-7572 
Library (Reeves Medical Library)  >>  569-7240 
Materials Management  >>  569-7209 
Medical Education  >>  569-7315 
Medical Records  >>  569-7306 
Medical Social Services  >>  569-8273 
Neonatology  >>  569-7522 
Nutrition  >>  569-7216 
Occupational Therapy  >>  569-7201 
Outpatient Surgery  >>  569-7287 
Pathology  >>  569-7367 
Patient Business Services  >>  879-8900 
Patient Grievances  >>  879-8769 
Pediatric Hematology/Oncology  >>  569-8394 
Pediatric Intensive Care Unit  >>  569-8297 
Pediatric Services  >>  569-7273 
Perinatal Center  >>  569-8209 
Pharmacy  >>  569-8381 
Psychiatric Services  >>  569-7253 
Public Affairs  >>  879-8980 
Quality Improvement  >>  569-7244 
Radiology  >>  569-7279 
Research  >>  569-8976 
Respiratory Care  >>  569-7207 
Reeves Medical Library  >>  569-7240 
Speech Therapy  >>  569-7201 
Spiritual Care  >>  569-8386 
Surgical Education  >>  569-7316 
Surgical Services  >>  569-7255 
Therapy Services  >>  569-7201 
Utilization Management  >>  569-7292 
Volunteer Services  >>  569-7357
```

Comment: thank you for the comment. I tried running but after print '%s  >>  %s ' % (name, value)   when I hit enter...nothing happens? Sorry so new to python world..can you help?

Comment: ok hitting enter couple of times gave me this
In [2]: for tr in trs:
   ...:     name = tr.xpath('./td[1]//text()').extract()
   ...:     value = tr.xpath('./td[2]//text()').extract()
   ...:     name = name[0].strip() if name else 'n/a'
   ...:      value = value[0].strip() if value else 'n/a'
   ...:     print '%s  >>  %s ' % (name, value)
   ...:
  File "<ipython-input-2-c865e0f3966a>", line 5
    value = value[0].strip() if value else 'n/a'
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

If you want to paste code into IPython, try the %paste and %cpaste magic functions.

Comment: hehe figured it out... python ..identation very imp:D